# Binary Search Tree in Ruby

Tags: ruby, tree, binary-search

Binary Search Tree, with preorder traverse. What other methods should I add? How can I improve it?

```
class Bst

  attr_accessor :data, :left, :right

  def initialize(data)
    self.data = data
  end

  def insert(data)
    if  self.data < data
      if (self.right ) 
        self.right.insert(data)
      else  
        self.right = Bst.new(data)
      end  
    else
      if (self.left ) 
        self.left.insert(data)
      else  
        self.left = Bst.new(data)
      end  
    end      
  end

  def each(&blk)
    Bst.traverse_preorder(self,&blk)
  end

  def self.traverse_preorder(node, &blk)
    return unless node
    traverse_preorder(node.left,&blk) 
    blk.call(node.data)
    traverse_preorder(node.right,&blk)    
  end  

end
```

Comment: Well, you could add post- and in-order traversal, a remove method, rebalancing the tree after each operation, methods to get the tree height, item lookup ...

Comment: Ok, I will update with those.

Comment: @classyhacker Did you ever get around to updating it? I've got a review of what's currently here written up, but I'd like to let you edit everything in first.

Comment: I did, let me dig it up.

Comment: Hey, I'm gonna post my review now. If you'd like, you can post another question with the updated code and I'll review that as well, but it's been a couple of hours now and I'm getting kinda bored of waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a pre-order traversal; that's an [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first).

Answer (score 7):

*Note: Each tip assumes you followed all of the ones before.*

There are a bunch of trailing whitespace characters. Get rid of 'em. They're ugly.

`Bst` is a terrible class name. It means nothing out-of-context, and out-of-context is where it will be. I'd recommend renaming to `BinarySearchTree`.

In the `if` statements, there's sometimes an extra space before the close-paren but not after the open; I've only ever seen both or neither. Personally, I would just get rid of the parentheses entirely -- they're unnecessary.

Prefer `if obj.nil?` over `unless obj`. It makes it much clearer that it's checking the existence of an object, rather than, say, the result of a method called `obj`.

Prefer `@data` to `self.data`. It functions the same but it's far more standard to directly access instance variables, unless accessing it requires some guard clauses or the like. Ditto for `self.right` and `self.left`. The exception is when you're accessing the class from outside, in which case you obviously don't have direct access to instance variables.

Put a space after (but not before) commas -- so `traverse_preorder(node.left,&blk)` becomes `traverse_preorder(node.left, &blk)`.

In that method, I'd recommend changing `blk` to `block`, because it makes no sense to shorten it.

With these changes, here's what your code looks like:

```
class BinarySearchTree
  attr_accessor :data, :left, :right

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def insert(data)
    if @data < data
      if @right.nil?
        @right = BinarySearchTree.new(data)
      else
        @right.insert(data)
      end
    else
      if @left.nil?
        @left = BinarySearchTree.new(data)
      else
        @left.insert(data)
      end
    end
  end

  def each(&block)
    BinarySearchTree.traverse_preorder(&block)
  end

  def self.traverse_preorder(node, &block)
    node.left.traverse_preorder(&block)
    blk.call(node.data)
    node.right.traverse_preorder(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's pretty standard to call it BST, I don't think its a bad name. The self vs @ stuff makes sense, I wrote it a while back so I would write it differently now. `if` parenthesis is subjective, I will choose to leave it in for clarity. I think.nil? is redundant here.

Comment: @classyhacker Really? Well, I'm gonna let you call it whatever, then. I prefer longer, more descriptive names. The `if` parentheses is subjective, sure, but [the style guide most people follow](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-parens-if) says not to use them. `.nil?` is definitely redundant, but "It makes it much clearer that it's checking the existence of an object, rather than, say, the result of a method called `obj`."

Comment: Also I would leave this is as a class method. Recursive methods, that call themselves are best represented that way https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/llrecursion/lecture.html

Comment: @500_error Hmm, yes, an article which declares it should be static without explaining why. If you can provide an authoritative source (so _not_ one lesson in a college's course that doesn't explain anything) that explains the reasoning, feel free to link that. Or give a more precise location, instead of expecting that I'll read through a several page article because you say it has some evidence.

Comment: Java does the same thing, it has a collections class for static methods that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html.

Comment: @500_error Hmm, so it does. Fair enough. Removed that point from my answer.